# How to filter values of 2 columns in a dataframe from a second dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter 2 columns in a dataframe from another 2 columns in a second dataframe, the idea is to keep my index. Is important to process each pair of values from columns X and Y as a single entity. Here an example:

Original dataframe:

`Out[72]: 
   ID   X   Y
0   1   1  10
1   1   2  23
2   1  50  65
3   2  30   2
4   2   2   5
5   2   6   8
6   3  10   3
7   3  33   6
8   3   4  90`

Then, I establish 'ID' as an index:

`df.set_index(['ID'])
Out[74]: 
     X   Y
ID

1    1  10
1    2  23
1   50  65
2   30   2
2    2   5
2    6   8
3   10   3
3   33   6
3    4  90`

and this is the second dataframe:

`df2
Out[68]: 
    X    Y
0   4   90
1   2   23
2   8    6
3  30    2
4   2    5
5  61   81`

The desired output is:

`Out[78]: 
    X   Y
ID

1   2  23
2  30   2
2   2   5
3   4  90`

I was using `zip` and the `set` but that only works to compare lists.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `merge` on columns X and Y, with parameter `right_index' set to True:

```
df.merge(df2, on=['X', 'Y'], right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
     X   Y
ID        
1    2  23
2   30   2
2    2   5
3    4  90
```

Comment: I just can't help but feel that so many merge questions have been asked, it would be better to close as duplicate than answer then over and over again... what do you think?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Sure... I suspect that many new users don't know to look at merge.  I like showing them how to answer their question directly, but feel free to close this question and mark as dupe.

Comment: That's work for me

Comment: @JonathanPacheco  Glad, I am could help.  Happy coding.